# Python maths quiz importing data from a txt file and organising it

Tags: python, sorting

I'm currently doing the OCR computer science A453 CA, To summarize I was given 3 tasks, i have completed the first 2 but the last task is really giving me problems. My starting position is that i am meant to save scores from a maths test into a txt. file. The child's name, and score is saved in a file related to its class. For task 3 I am now asked to import this data to find the average scores and highest scores ordered highest to lowest and the scores arranged alphabetically. I have tried and tried but I cannot find a solution to this task. I have deleted all my experimental code to try to get it to work and have just left you with the code up until the scores are saved. Would be a great help to find a solution or even some good pointers on what to do! thanks :)

CODE:

```
username=input("What is your name?") #childs name variable
group=int(input("What class number are you, 1, 2 or 3?")) #this determines which file the score will be saved in
print ("Welcome {} to the Arithmetic quiz".format(username))#The introduction to the quiz

correctAnswers=0
for question_number in range(10):
    if test():
        correctAnswers +=1

print("{}: You got {} answers correct".format(username, correctAnswers))


if group==1:#If the childs class 1,their score will be saved in the file for the class:1
    with open("class1.txt","a+") as f:
        f.write("{}:{}".format(username,correctAnswers))
if group==2:#If the childs class is equal to 2, the file will be saved in the file for class:2
    with open("class2.txt","a+") as f:
        f.write("{}:{}".format(username,correctAnswers))
if group==3:#If the childs class is equal to 3, the file will be saved in the file for class:3
    with open("class3.txt","a+") as f:
        f.write("{}:{}".format(username,correctAnswers))
```

Comment: Sorry for the awful format but i could not get the code to paste properly, If you have any suggestions to be able to post it properly, please say

Comment: To properly format code, you can highlight it in the editor and press control+K or click on the button that looks like {}.

Comment: Ah many thanks, will remember that in future.

Comment: Im all out of ideas and need some pointers, im not asking for full answers, just hints :)